# How to display html as firefox panel without using sdk

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, panel

I need to display html elements as contents of a popup panel using javascript in my firefox addon.

Displaying popup using SDK is what I'm looking for but I don't want to use SDK.

panel:

```
<popupset id="mainPopupSet">
    <panel id="htmlPanel" type="arrow">
        i want to use html elements like p,div,span, etc here.
    </panel>
</popupset>
```

javascript to open panel:

```
document.getElementById('htmlPanel').innerHTML = 'my custom contents';
document.getElementById('htmlPanel').openPopup(null, "before_start", 0, 0, false, false);
```

it seems some elements are allowed but with different behavior! i also need to set CSS for elements inside panel.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out how to do it using an `iframe`

changed the XUL as follow:

```
<popupset id="mainPopupSet">
    <panel id="htmlPanel" type="arrow">
        <html:iframe id="htmlContainer"/>
    </panel>
</popupset>
```

and create a javascript function to set html contents:

```
function setupPanel(contents, width, height)
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById("htmlContainer");
    iframe.setAttribute("src","data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(contents));
    iframe.width = width || 300; //default width=300
    iframe.height = height || 300; //default height=300
}
```

and usage:

```
setupPanel("<p>this is raw HTML.</p>");
document.getElementById('htmlPanel').openPopup(null, "before_start", 0, 0, false, false);
```

thanks for your hints.

Comment: make sure to use html namespaces on the iframe like @paa did below. otehrwise you will run into problems like on load listeners: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2809781&hilit=iframe+html+namespace

Answer (score 0):

With animation can copy paste to scratchpad to run it.

```
var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
var panel = win.document.createElement('panel');
var props = {
    type: 'arrow',
    style: 'width:300px;height:100px;'
}
for (var p in props) {
    panel.setAttribute(p, props[p]);
}

win.document.querySelector('#mainPopupSet').appendChild(panel);

panel.addEventListener('popuphiding', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    //panel.removeEventListener('popuphiding', arguments.callee, false); //if dont have this then cant do hidepopup after animation as hiding will be prevented
    panel.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
        //panel.hidePopup(); //just hide it, if want this then comment out line 19 also uncomment line 16
        panel.parentNode.removeChild(panel); //remove it from dom //if want this then comment out line 18
    }, false);
    panel.ownerDocument.getAnonymousNodes(panel)[0].setAttribute('style', 'transform:translate(0,-50px);opacity:0.9;transition: transform 0.2s ease-in, opacity 0.15s ease-in');
}, false);

panel.openPopup(null, 'overlap', 100, 100);
```

to display html in it, do `createElementNS('html namespace i cant recall right now','iframe')` then set the src of this to the html you want it to display

the `type:'arrow'` here is important

Answer (score 0):

Since this appears to be an overlay of `browser.xul`, if your panel will display static content or a simple template, you can take advantage of the fact that the XHTML namespace is already declared.

```xml
<popupset id="mainPopupSet">
  <panel id="htmlPanel" type="arrow">
    <html:div id="htmlplaceholder">
      <html:p>Lorem ipsum</html:p>
      <html:p>foo <html:strong>bar</html:strong></html:p>
    </html:div>
  </panel>
</popupset>
```

The Add-on SDK hosts the html content inside an `iframe`, perhaps you should consider this for more complex cases.